# Tcp Socket server in C#

Tags: c#, sockets, tcp, ip-address

I have found this piece of code on the internet: it does not open a server listening on port 11000, as I hoped.

What can be the problem? I normally code in Delphi, so I am little lost. I have made a corresponding client in Delphi, which works.

I am using demo version of C# 2015.

```
    public static void StartListening()
    {
        // Data buffer for incoming data.
        byte[] bytes = new Byte[1024];

        // Establish the local endpoint for the socket.
        // Dns.GetHostName returns the name of the 
        // host running the application.
        IPHostEntry ipHostInfo = Dns.Resolve(Dns.GetHostName());
        IPAddress ipAddress = ipHostInfo.AddressList[0];
        IPEndPoint localEndPoint = new IPEndPoint(ipAddress, 11000);

        // Create a TCP/IP socket.
        Socket listener = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork,
            SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);

        // Bind the socket to the local endpoint and 
        // listen for incoming connections.
        try
        {
            listener.Bind(localEndPoint);
            listener.Listen(10);

            // Start listening for connections.
            while (true)
            {
                //Console.WriteLine("Waiting for a connection...");
                // Program is suspended while waiting for an incoming connection.
                Socket handler = listener.Accept();
                data = null;

                // An incoming connection needs to be processed.
                while (true)
                {
                    bytes = new byte[1024];
                    int bytesRec = handler.Receive(bytes);
                    data += Encoding.ASCII.GetString(bytes, 0, bytesRec);
                    if (data.IndexOf("#") > -1)
                    {
                        break;
                    }
                }

                // Show the data on the console.
                //Console.WriteLine("Text received : {0}", data);

                // Echo the data back to the client.
                byte[] msg = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(data);

                handler.Send(msg);
                handler.Shutdown(SocketShutdown.Both);
                handler.Close();
            }

        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e.ToString());
        }

        //Console.WriteLine("\nPress ENTER to continue...");
        //Console.Read();

    }
```

Comment: What is the exception from `bind`?

Comment: Thank you very much. No exception on bind.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The problem might be here: Whats the IP address of `ipHostInfo.AddressList[0]` ? It might be the loop-back. I never restrict my server endpoint to an ip-adress unless I need to, but then I will specify it in a configfile.

```
IPEndPoint localEndPoint = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, 11000);
```

Comment: That was the problem, exactly, Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

As per [Jeroen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39572991/tcp-socket-server-in-c-sharp/39573094#39573094)'s answer, encountered per .NET's [Synchronous Server Socket Example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/network-programming/synchronous-server-socket-example). When listening/connecting to localhost, one should rather use

```
IPAddress ipAddress = IPAddress.Parse("127.0.0.1");
```

instead of

```
// Establish the local endpoint for the socket.  
// Dns.GetHostName returns the name of the   
// host running the application.  
IPHostEntry ipHostInfo = Dns.GetHostEntry(Dns.GetHostName());  
IPAddress ipAddress = ipHostInfo.AddressList[0];
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for feedback. I found som other, older code:

```
TcpListener serverSocket = new TcpListener(11000);
```

that does the job. I know it is depreciated, but it works, actually.

Comment: If you take a look [into the code](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System/net/System/Net/Sockets/TCPListener.cs,b4b3fb30f684759a) you'll see it does exactly the same as @Jeroen mentioned in his answer. So you should at least upvote his answer and/or accept it.